# Proving the second direction of Schur's complement

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following **Schur's complement** lemma:

For every block matrix $M$:

$$
M=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{P} & \mathbf{Q}^T \\
\mathbf{Q} & \mathbf{R} \\
\end{array} \right), R\succ0
$$

The Schur complement $S\triangleq P-Q^TR^{-1}Q$ holds:
$$S\succ0\iff M\succ0$$

---

I've shown that for every vector $x$, partitioned to $x=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
u \\
v \\
\end{array} \right)$ similarly to $M$:
$$\forall u,v: f(u,v)=(u^T \ v^T)M\left( \begin{array}{cc}
u \\
v \\
\end{array} \right)=u^TPu+2v^TQu+v^TRv$$ 
Then I've found the optimal $v^*$ and got:
$$\forall u: f(u,v^*)=u^T(P-Q^TR^{-1}Q)u=u^TSu$$

---

From here, and due to $f$'s convexity when $M\succ0$, proving the first direction was easy:

$$
M\succ0\Rightarrow \forall u,v: (u^T \ v^T)M\left( \begin{array}{cc}
u \\
v \\
\end{array} \right)=f(u,v)\underset{convexity}{\geq}f(u,v^*)=u^TSu\underset{M\succ 0}{\gt}0\Longrightarrow S\succ 0
$$

---

I got stuck on the opposite direction:
$$
S\succ 0\Rightarrow \forall u:f(u,v^*)=u^TSu>0
$$
But since I don't know yet that $M\succ0$, I guess that $f$ is not necessarily convex, so I also don't know that $f(u,v)\geq f(u,v^*)$, and can't finish my proof.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I believe that I've found the answer.

At the last stage we got:

$$
S\succ 0\Rightarrow \forall u:f(u,v^*)=u^TSu>0
$$

The problem was that we also needed to show that $f(u,v)\geq f(u,v^*)$ holds in this direction as well.

If we again fix $u$ and calculate the hessian of $f(u,v)$, we get $\nabla^2f=R \succ 0$, meaning that once again, $f(u,v)\geq f(u,v^*)$, and overall we get what we wanted:

$$
S\succ 0\Rightarrow \forall u,v:(u^T \ v^T)M\left( \begin{array}{cc}
u \\
v \\
\end{array} \right)=f(u,v)\geq f(u,v^*)=u^TSu>0 \Longrightarrow M\succ0
$$

And combining both directions:
$$M\succ0\iff S\succ 0 \ \ \ \blacksquare$$